# pm2-runtime executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: docker, dockerfile, pm2

Host is running MacOS X High Sierra

Running a NodeJS app in a docker container.

Using [Docker PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/docker-pm2-nodejs/) integration i.e. `pm2-runtime`

## Docker version

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:   18.04.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    3d479c0
 Built: Tue Apr 10 18:13:16 2018
 OS/Arch:   darwin/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:  18.04.0-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.4
  Git commit:   3d479c0
  Built:    Tue Apr 10 18:23:05 2018
  OS/Arch:  linux/amd64
  Experimental: true
```

## Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine

COPY . ./app

WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install --no-optional
RUN npm install bcrypt --no-optional
RUN npm install bcrypt pm2 --no-optional

ENV NODE_ENV staging
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "ecosystem.config.json"]

EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 8443
```

## Run log

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -p 8443:8443 -i -t wrapper:0.2
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"pm2-runtime\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

Any pointers?

Comment: I’m having the same issue, any luck with this?

Answer (score 3):

Install pm2 globally like

`npm install pm2 -g`

Or pass pm2-runtime full path.